# Datomic entity-api is slow on large amount of entities?

Tags: clojure, scalability, datomic

I need to apply additional logic (like mapping, conditionals, aggregating) to entities I get from Datomic. I had hard time translating it to Datomic query (I'm not sure if it's even possible in my case), which is why I used datomic's raw index access instead, so the most work and logic is done in Clojure.

It worked fine until I got to ~500K entries and the whole approach is getting very slow.
The relevant code:

```
(defn e->entry
  "Map e into entry"
  [e]
  {:id   (:entry/uuid e)
   ;; each flat field increases mapping time (seems linearly)
   :date (:entry/date e)
   :summ (:entry/summ e)   
   ;; although when using nested fields, mapping time rises significantly
   :groups (map #(-> % :dimension/group :group/name) 
                (:entry/dimensions e))})


;; query code:
(->> (d/datoms db :aevt :entry/uuid)
     (map #(->> % 
                :e
                (d/entity db)
                e->entry))))
     ;; TODO: other actions on mapped entries ...
```

It takes about *30 seconds* to run query code just to map entities and the more fields I need in my query, the more it takes.

Is this an expected behavior? Is there a way I can speed things up or am I missing something and this is bad approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with following optimizations, in case someone will need it:

```
(defn eid->entry
  "Mapping via :eavt index"
  [db eid]
  (->> (d/datoms db :eavt eid) ; access all datoms by eid once
       (seq)
       (reduce (fn [m dtm]
                 (let [attr-key (d/ident db (:a dtm))
                       v (:v dtm)]
                   (assoc m attr-key v))))))

;; new query code
(->> (d/datoms db :aevt :entry/uuid)
     (pmap #(->> % 
                 :e
                 (eid->entry db))))
```

I used pmap instead of map and resorted to `:eavt` index to get all attributes and values of entity instead of accessing fields directly with `d/entity`

Answer (score 1):

To fully answer this question would require more information, please feel free to [ask on the forum or open a support ticket](https://www.datomic.com/support.html).